# How do I update the badge number for uitabbaritem when a new push notification arrives

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

How can I update the badge for a specific UITabBarItem when a new push notification arrives? 
For example like the activity tab in Instagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following code:

```
[[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] 
               objectAtIndex:tabIndex] setBadgeValue:badgeValueString];
```

Comment: Yes but how do I access the tabbarController from the AppDelegate where the push notification is handled?

Comment: Where you have created tabbarcontroller? I guess, it should be in AppDelegate

Comment: I just dragged it to the storyboard

Comment: Please check : self.window.rootViewController. Is it tabbarcontroller instance?

Comment: rootViewController is a UIView. When I try to access rootViewController.tabBarController I get nil

Comment: How rootviewcontroller can be UIView? It can be UIViewController or UINavigationController or UITabbarController.

Comment: Sorry I meant UIViewController :)

Comment: In AppDelegate, Can you get the instance of ViewController, currently present? If yes, you have to get it and check currentViewController.tabbarController . If not, rootviewController must be a UINavigationController object and you can get [[navController.viewControllers lastObject] tabbarController] will provide the tabbar controller instance

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (long)countUnreadMessages];

[[[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:indexOfTabbarItem] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:([badgeValue isEqualToString:@"0"]) ? nil : badgeValue];
```